# Manage two level of arraylist from nested arraylist in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, collections

This is My Model Class Which is used to Handle API response

```
data class CommunityCommentListDataModel
    (
    @SerializedName("data")
    var `data`: Data = Data(),
    @SerializedName("message")
    var message: String = "",
    @SerializedName("response")
    var response: String = "",
    @SerializedName("status_code")
    var statusCode: Int = 0
) {
    data class Data(
        @SerializedName("comment_count")
        var commentCount: String = "",
        @SerializedName("list")
        var list: List<Comment> = listOf()
    ) {
        data class Comment(
            @SerializedName("community_id")
            var communityId: String = "",
            @SerializedName("created_at")
            var createdAt: String = "",
            @SerializedName("description")
            var description: String = "",
            @SerializedName("get_user")
            var getUser: GetUser = GetUser(),
            @SerializedName("id")
            var id: String = "",
            @SerializedName("parent_id")
            var parentId: String = "",
            @SerializedName("sub_comment")
            var subComment: List<Comment> = listOf(),
            @SerializedName("updated_at")
            var updatedAt: String = "",
            @SerializedName("user_id")
            var userId: String = "",
            @SerializedName("comment_like_count")
            var commentLikeCount: Int = 0,
            @SerializedName("liked_by_user")
            var likedByUser: String = "",
            var isSubCommentDisplay:Boolean=false
        ) 
    }
}
```

It will Manage N level of sub comment data from API.

In API I will get N level of data and we need to display all comment max 2 level,I Need to set sub comment data to mx 2 level.

Also need to add/update data to specific position.

Please Help.